# Libusb error for Input and Output under Ubuntu Linux - C programming for USB

Tags: c, usb, libusb, usbserial

I have made a C-program that should talk USB. But I have got an error -1 that says I have som Input/Output errors.

My C code is here below. I going to explain how it works. The function `getDevices()` print out the `vendor ID` and the `product ID` and also the `device name`. Remember those when you running the function `getDevices()`.

Then you have to choose what device you want to connect. When you have choose the device, then you write in the `vendor ID` and `product ID` here.

```
#define USB_VENDOR_ID   1155
#define USB_PRODUCT_ID  14415 /* USB product ID used by the device */
```

After that, you need to run the function `connectUSB()`. It simply connect to your USB depening on which `USB_VENDOR_ID` and `USB_PRODUCT_ID` you have been written.

I have issues to read the incomming message. I got the error `LIBUSB_ERROR_IO = -1` when I try to read.

So why does I get `-1` error when I try to read? I have tried with:

- Run the C-code as full administration rights, e.g root
- Unmout the USB device inside the computer, not plug it out
- Tested to have a USB reader software ON meanwhile I use this C-program

If you want to try my code, you have to install `LibUSB`. From debbased systems such as Debian, Ubuntu, Raspberry etc. it can be done by writing this command in the terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0.0-dev libusb-1.0-0
```

My C-code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>
#include <string.h>

libusb_context *CONTEXT; //a libusb session
libusb_device_handle *DEVICEHANDLE; //a device handle
libusb_device * DEVICE_POINTER; // a pointer to a device
libusb_device **ARRAY_OF_POINTERS_TO_DEVICE; // an array of pointers to devices
ssize_t NUMBER_OF_USB_DEVICES; // Initial zero devices

static uint8_t receiveBuf[64];
uint8_t transferBuf[64];

uint16_t counter = 0;
#define USB_ENDPOINT_IN     0x80   /* endpoint address */
#define USB_ENDPOINT_OUT    0x01  /* endpoint address */
#define USB_TIMEOUT 3000 /* Connection timeout (in ms) */
#define USB_VENDOR_ID   1155
#define USB_PRODUCT_ID  14415 /* USB product ID used by the device */

/*
 * Here we are going to read the USB
 */
int readUSB() {
    int nread, r, counter = 0;
    nread = 4;
    int transfered;
    unsigned char data[4];

    r = libusb_bulk_transfer(DEVICEHANDLE, USB_ENDPOINT_IN, data, nread, &transfered, USB_TIMEOUT);
    if (LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT == r) {
        printf("LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT = %d\n", r);
        return -1;
    }else if(LIBUSB_ERROR_PIPE == r){
        printf("LIBUSB_ERROR_PIPE = %d\n", r);
        return -1;
    }else if(LIBUSB_ERROR_OVERFLOW == r){
        printf("LIBUSB_ERROR_OVERFLOW = %d\n", r);
        return -1;
    }else if(LIBUSB_ERROR_NO_DEVICE == r){
        printf("LIBUSB_ERROR_NO_DEVICE = %d\n", r);
        return -1;
    }else if(LIBUSB_ERROR_IO == r){
        printf("LIBUSB_ERROR_IO = %d\n", r);
        return -1;
    } else {
        printf("r = %d, %d receive %d bytes from device: %s\n", r, ++counter, nread, data);
        return 0;
    }


    return 0;
}

/*
 * Here are we going to write to the USB
 */
int writeUSB() {
    int n, ret;
    uint16_t count = 0;
    //count up
    n = sprintf(transferBuf, "%d\0", count++);
    //write transfer
    //probably unsafe to use n twice...
    ret = libusb_bulk_transfer(DEVICEHANDLE, USB_ENDPOINT_OUT, transferBuf, n,
            &n, USB_TIMEOUT);
    //Error handling
    switch (ret) {
    case 0:
        printf("send %d bytes to device\n", n);
        return 0;
    case LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT:
        printf("ERROR in bulk write: %d Timeout\n", ret);
        break;
    case LIBUSB_ERROR_PIPE:
        printf("ERROR in bulk write: %d Pipe\n", ret);
        break;
    case LIBUSB_ERROR_OVERFLOW:
        printf("ERROR in bulk write: %d Overflow\n", ret);
        break;
    case LIBUSB_ERROR_NO_DEVICE:
        printf("ERROR in bulk write: %d No Device\n", ret);
        break;
    default:
        printf("ERROR in bulk write: %d\n", ret);
        break;

    }
    return -1;
    return 0;
}

/*
 * This will connect to our USB device
 */
int connectUSB() {
    int r;
    r = libusb_init(&CONTEXT);
    if(r > 0){
        printf("Libusb_init error %d\n", r);
        return -1;
    }
    //libusb_set_debug(CONTEXT, 0);

    //Open Device with VendorID and ProductID
    DEVICEHANDLE = libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(CONTEXT, USB_VENDOR_ID, USB_PRODUCT_ID);
    if (DEVICEHANDLE == NULL) {
        perror("DEVICEHANDLE == NULL");
        return -1;
    }

    //Claim Interface 0 from the device
    r = libusb_claim_interface(DEVICEHANDLE, 0);
    if (r == LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_FOUND) {
        fprintf(stderr, "LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_FOUND = %d\n", r);
        return -1;
    }else if(r == LIBUSB_ERROR_BUSY){
        fprintf(stderr, "LIBUSB_ERROR_BUSY = %d\n", r);
        return -1;
    }else if(r == LIBUSB_ERROR_NO_DEVICE){
        fprintf(stderr, "LIBUSB_ERROR_NO_DEVICE = %d\n", r);
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Interface claimed\n");
    return 0;
}

/*
 * This will show all the devices for USB and send it thru sockets
 */
int getDevices() {

    /*
     * Special local device handle for only get the name of the USB device
     */
    libusb_device_handle *DEVICEHANDLE_NULL; //a device handle

    /*
     * Compute the number of USB
     */
    int returnValue = libusb_init(NULL);
    NUMBER_OF_USB_DEVICES = libusb_get_device_list(NULL,
            &ARRAY_OF_POINTERS_TO_DEVICE);

    /*
     * Create our list of Vendor, Product and device
     * Vendor and product are important for connect the USB and device is important for the user to see which USB to connect
     */
    uint16_t vendor[NUMBER_OF_USB_DEVICES];
    uint16_t product[NUMBER_OF_USB_DEVICES];
    char device[NUMBER_OF_USB_DEVICES][256 * 2];

    /*
     * Loop thru all USB devices
     */
    ssize_t deviceIndex = 0;
    while (deviceIndex < NUMBER_OF_USB_DEVICES) {

        /*
         * Get the description of the USB device
         */
        DEVICE_POINTER = ARRAY_OF_POINTERS_TO_DEVICE[deviceIndex];
        struct libusb_device_descriptor deviceDescriptor;
        returnValue = libusb_get_device_descriptor(DEVICE_POINTER,
                &deviceDescriptor);
        if (returnValue != LIBUSB_SUCCESS)
            break;

        /*
         * Open the USB device with NULL. It's only because we want the name of the USB device
         */
        DEVICEHANDLE_NULL = NULL;
        returnValue = libusb_open(DEVICE_POINTER, &DEVICEHANDLE_NULL);
        if (returnValue != LIBUSB_SUCCESS) {
            /*
             * There was an error. Not success.
             */

            if (DEVICEHANDLE_NULL != NULL) {
                libusb_close(DEVICEHANDLE_NULL);
                DEVICEHANDLE_NULL = NULL;
            }

            /*
             * Write as there was no info at all to display
             */
            product[deviceIndex] = 0;
            vendor[deviceIndex] = 0;
            memcpy(device[deviceIndex], "-", 256 * 2 * sizeof(char));
            deviceIndex++;
            continue;

        }

        /*
         * Get the string associated with iManufacturer index.
         */
        const int STRING_LENGTH = 256;
        unsigned char stringManufacturer[STRING_LENGTH];
        unsigned char stringProduct[STRING_LENGTH];
        char stringDeviceName[STRING_LENGTH * 2];
        if (DEVICEHANDLE_NULL != NULL && deviceDescriptor.iManufacturer > 0) {
            returnValue = libusb_get_string_descriptor_ascii(DEVICEHANDLE_NULL,
                    deviceDescriptor.iManufacturer, stringManufacturer,
                    STRING_LENGTH);
            if (returnValue < 0)
                break;
        }

        /*
         * Get string associated with iProduct index.
         */
        if (DEVICEHANDLE_NULL != NULL && deviceDescriptor.iProduct > 0) {
            returnValue = libusb_get_string_descriptor_ascii(DEVICEHANDLE_NULL,
                    deviceDescriptor.iProduct, stringProduct, STRING_LENGTH);
            if (returnValue < 0)
                break;
        }

        /*
         * Combine manufacturer and product
         */
        strcpy(stringDeviceName, (char*) stringManufacturer);
        strcat(stringDeviceName, " "); // a space only
        strcat(stringDeviceName, (char*) stringProduct);
        //printf("%s\n", stringDeviceName);

        /*
         * Save them all into arrays
         */
        product[deviceIndex] = deviceDescriptor.idProduct;
        vendor[deviceIndex] = deviceDescriptor.idVendor;
        memcpy(device[deviceIndex], stringDeviceName, 256 * 2 * sizeof(char));

        /*
         * Close and try next one.
         */
        if (DEVICEHANDLE_NULL != NULL) {
            libusb_close(DEVICEHANDLE_NULL);
            DEVICEHANDLE_NULL = NULL;
        }

        /*
         * Next USB device
         */
        deviceIndex++;
    }

    /*
     * Print our result what we found and send them to socket
     */
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        printf("Name: %s\n", device[i]);
        printf("Vendor: %u\n", vendor[i]);
        printf("Product: %u\n\n", product[i]);
    }

    libusb_exit(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *But I have got an error -1 that says I have som Input/Output errors.* -  I am pretty sure it is saying something more useful.

Comment: TL;DR why your writeUSB has 
return - 1;
return 0; at the end? (always return - 1)

Comment: @Nico238 Sorry. I have forgot that.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes. But what? I have looked inside the documention, but haven't found anything that says what "-1" means.